# MEAN+Docker: Hide backend from outside the world

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx

I'm new to the backend. And I'm trying to server my application made on the MEAN stack using Docker-compose.

I have app: Docker + Nginx. Angular Frontend + Node.js Backend.
Problem: to hide my backend from outside the world

My docker-compose.yml: (one network)

```
version: '3'
services:
  front: ..... # NO PORTS
  back: .... # No PORTS
  nginx:
    .......
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    .......
  certbot: .....
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

My nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html;
    }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name ....
    server_tokens off;
    ssl_ ....
    location /back {
            try_files $uri @back;
    }
    location @back {
        proxy_pass http://back:3001;
        rewrite ^/back/(.*) /$1 break;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
    }
    location / {....}
    location @front {
        proxy_pass http://front:80;
        add_header ..... 
    }
}
```

Angular service TS:

```
getItems() {
    return this.http.get('/back/items')
      .pipe(map( res => res))
}
```

Comment: That seems like a reasonable setup; what problem are you running into?

Comment: @DavidMaze I need to hide my backend from outside the world.
At this moment I can access the backend just by typing the appropriate url. I need my frontend to be able to communicate to the backend, but that my backend is not accessible via the normal link.

Comment: Your frontend is running in the user's browser, so it's hard to make your backend inaccessible but at the same time make it accessible from your app running in the user's browser.

Comment: Intrinsically, your application runs in some end user's browser and needs to make requests to the backend; the backend _must_ be exported in some way.  (The application does not run in a container and often won't be on your local system, and can't use Docker networking.)

Comment: @DavidMaze How do Docker and Nginx usually work in such cases? Maybe there is some way to configure the ip restriction of the frontend container? Or somehow use internal parameter in nginx.conf?

Comment: It usually looks very much like what you've shown in the question: the backend APIs that are called from the front-end application (running in the end user's browser, somewhere out on the network) are made visible on a specific path in the Nginx proxy.  You can't hide those endpoints and also have them called from the browser application.